# Resolving SVN userids to email address in hudson using email-ext plugin

Tags: hudson-plugins

I have tried using Hudson's Email ext plugin by selecting "Include the culprits" but it gives only the svn id for which i should be able to resolve as email address.How to do it in Hudson?

Comment: My requirement is to trigger emails for the person who are culprits for making the build failed.In my svn the id comes at nt userid with a combination of first two letters from surname and last name suppose for example if svn id is kupankaj then email id is kumar.pankaj@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

By default the email extension plugin will try to send mail to svnuser@domain.com. In order to send mail to the correct id, either you should reconfigure svn access using email id or you should provide email address for each users under "user configuration" in Hudson. You can do this via GUI. Hudson >> People >> User >> Configure >> provide the correct email address and save.